# Be able to pass the installation directory with a custom installshield setup

Tags: visual-studio-2013, parameter-passing, custom-action, installshield-le

@all,

I am trying to create an InstallShield installation (the one that can be integrated in visual studio 2013)

In the tab custom actions I'd like to start a program that is placed in the [commonfolder]. As a commandline parameter I want to pass the installation path the user give to install the application.

See the attached illustration. Now as you can see the command line already has a some info I want to pass the install dir. as a parameter.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it just that simple??

Comment: Yes it is that simple :) It works perfect @MichaelUrman