# Adding an application manifest with requireAdministrator breaks Installshield custom action

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, uac, custom-action, installshield-le

@All,

I was successful in adding and running a custom action see ([Be able to pass the installation directory with a custom installshield setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805627/be-able-to-pass-the-installation-directory-with-a-custom-installshield-setup))

This application needs to run with Administrator rights so I added these (add an application manifest to my c# application and set the following execution level `'<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />'`

When rebuilding the setup and deploying it on the same machine I now get the message that the file cannot be found see the image below

[image]

App.manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <!-- UAC Manifest Options
            If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
            requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

            Specifying requestedExecutionLevel node will disable file and registry virtualization.
            If you want to utilize File and Registry Virtualization for backward 
            compatibility then delete the requestedExecutionLevel node.
        -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!-- A list of all Windows versions that this application is designed to work with. 
      Windows will automatically select the most compatible environment.-->

      <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows Vista, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"></supportedOS>-->

      <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows 7, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>-->

      <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows 8, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"></supportedOS>-->

      <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows 8.1, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>-->

    </application>
  </compatibility>

  <!-- Enable themes for Windows common controls and dialogs (Windows XP and later) -->
  <!-- <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
          type="win32"
          name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
          version="6.0.0.0"
          processorArchitecture="*"
          publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
          language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>-->

</asmv1:assembly>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it work when you remove the `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`? I do not fully understand why the assembly manifest should break the installer. Or is this assembly run as custom action?

Comment: The assembly using the manifest is run as a custom action indeed.
Just as a setup.exe file for example. Which can be run without any problems

Comment: @C Sharper - very very strange when removing the <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" /> line it works. What can be the reason here?

Comment: I'm not sure about. But any Custom action run maybe not with elevate priviliges (admin) and this could be the reason why it fails.

Comment: Ic. Well thanks for pointing me into the right direction much obliged :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any custom action run not with elevated privileges (administrator) and this could be the reason why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your custom action directly launches an .exe file, Windows Installer uses CreateProcess rather than ShellExecute behind the scenes, and this does not elevate during the process launch. So that means you have to use a custom action scheduling that is already elevated.

In the limited edition, only the two scheduling locations "After Register Product" and "After System Changes" are elevated.